# ggplot2, histogram: why do y = ..density.. and stat = "density" differ?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

Say I have this data frame `df`:

```
structure(list(max.diff = c(6.02, 7.56, 7.79, 7.43, 7.21, 7.65, 
8.1, 7.35, 7.57, 9.09, 6.21, 8.2, 6.82, 7.18, 7.78, 8.27, 6.85, 
6.72, 6.67, 6.99, 7.32, 6.59, 6.86, 6.02, 8.5, 7.25, 5.18, 8.85, 
5.44, 6.44, 7.85, 6.25, 9.06, 8.19, 5.08, 6.26, 8.92, 6.83, 6.5, 
7.55, 7.31, 5.83, 5.55, 4.29, 8.29, 8.72, 9.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-47L), .Names = "max.diff")
```

I want to plot this as a density plot using `ggplot2`:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = max.diff)) 
p <- p + geom_histogram(stat = "density")
print(p)
```

which gives,

[image]

Now, a naive question: why doesn't this give the same result?

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = max.diff)) 
p <- p + geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..))
print(p)
```

[image]

Is this because of the chosen `binwidth` or number of `bins` or some other parameter? So far, I haven't been able to tweak those parameters to make them the same. Or am I plotting something quite different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second example is rescaling the histogram counts so that bar areas integrate to 1, but is otherwise the same as the standard ggplot2 histogram. You can adjust the number of bars with the `bins` or the `binwidth` arguments.

The first example is calculating a kernel density estimate and plotting the output (the estimated density at each x-value) as a histogram. You can change the amount of smoothing of the density estimate with the `adjust` argument, and the number of points at which the density is calculated using the `n` argument.

The default for `geom_histogram` is `bins=30`. The default for `stat="density"` is `adjust=1` and `n=512` (`stat="density"` is using the `density` function to generate the values). The `stat="density"` output is much smoother than the histogram output due to the way `density` chooses the bandwidth for the density estimate. Reducing the `adjust` argument reduces the amount of smoothing.

The first two examples below are your plots. The second two use adjustments to the respective parameters to get two plots that are roughly similar, though not exactly the same because the kernel density estimate is still smoothing the output. This is just for illustration. The kernel density estimate and the histogram are two different, thought related, things.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = max.diff)) +
  geom_histogram(stat = "density") +
  ggtitle("stat='density'; default paramters")

ggplot(df, aes(x = max.diff)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), colour="white") +
  ggtitle("geom_histogram; default parameters")

ggplot(df, aes(x = max.diff)) +
  geom_histogram(stat = "density", n=2^5, adjust=0.1) +
  ggtitle("stat='density'; n=2^5; Adjust=0.1")

ggplot(df, aes(x = max.diff)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), bins=2^5, colour="white") +
  ggtitle("geom_histogram; bins=2^5")
```

[image]